# Postgresql. Множество параллельных запросов и INSERT ... ON CONFLICT

Tags: postgresql

Сейчас в сервис летит куча запросов от 1к до 10к в секунду. И справочник обновляется с помощью INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ... DO UPDATE SET updated_at = NOW(), т.е. получается большое количество транзакций. Видно, что на пиковых значениях, когда  количество запросов в секунду сильно подскакивает до 10к, то запрос INSERT... начинает работать дольше. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким? Может есть более элегантное решение? Уникальных значений может быть не так много, например на 10к уникальных приходится штук 100 - 200.